# Convert keep dense_rank from Oracle query into postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, dense-rank

I'm trying to convert the following Oracle query into Postgres

```
select
        this_.GLOBAL_TRANSACTION_ID as y0_,
        this_.BUSINESS_IDENTIFIER as y1_,
        this_.ENVIRONMENT as y2_,
        count(*) as y3_,
        this_.HOST_NAME as y4_,
        listagg(process,
        ', ') within
    group (order by
        date_time) as process,
        min(this_.DATE_TIME) as y6_,
        max(this_.DATE_TIME) as y7_,
        max(status)keep(dense_rank last
    order by
        date_time,
        decode(status,
        'COMPLETED',
        'd',
        'FAILED',
        'c',
        'TERMINATED',
        'b',
        'STARTED',
        'a',
        'z')) as status
    from
        ACTIVITY_MONITOR_TRANSACTION this_
    where
        this_.DATE_TIME between ? and ?
        and 1=1
    group by
        this_.GLOBAL_TRANSACTION_ID,
        this_.BUSINESS_IDENTIFIER,
        this_.ENVIRONMENT,
        this_.HOST_NAME,
        global_transaction_id,
        business_identifier,
        global_transaction_id,
        business_identifier
    order by
        y7_ asc
```

the problem is I don't know how to convert this block:

```
max(status)keep(dense_rank last
    order by
        date_time,
        decode(status,
        'COMPLETED',
        'd',
        'FAILED',
        'c',
        'TERMINATED',
        'b',
        'STARTED',
        'a',
        'z')) as status
```

The aim of this block is to get the **latest** status, and in case of exact same time (it is possible!) assign the status following the order above.

```
This is an example of data:
      ID        DATA_TIME          GLOBAL_TRANSACTION_ID   STATUS
===================================================================
 54938456;"2015-04-20 09:39:27";"8d276718-eca7-4fd0-a266 ;"STARTED"
 54938505;"2015-04-20 09:39:27";"8d276718-eca7-4fd0-a266 ;"COMPLETED"
 54938507;"2015-04-20 09:39:27";"8d276718-eca7-4fd0-a266 ;"FAILED"
 54938507;"2015-04-20 09:38:25";"8d276718-eca7-4fd0-a266 ;"FAILED"
```

The status should be "COMPLETED" so my query should return, among other rows, the following:

```
 GLOBAL_TRANSACTION_ID    COUNT    (...)       STATUS
=====================================================
 8d276718-eca7-4fd0-a266    4      (...)     COMPLETED
```

I have tried splitting the query into 2:

```
select
    this_.GLOBAL_TRANSACTION_ID as y0_,
    this_.BUSINESS_IDENTIFIER as y1_,
    this_.ENVIRONMENT as y2_,
    count(*) as y3_,
    this_.HOST_NAME as y4_,
    array_to_string(array_agg(distinct process),
    ',') as process,
    min(this_.DATE_TIME) as y6_,
    max(this_.DATE_TIME) as y7_,
    max(this_.STATUS) as y8_
from
    ACTIVITY_MONITOR_TRANSACTION this_
where
    this_.DATE_TIME between ? and ?
group by
    this_.GLOBAL_TRANSACTION_ID,
    this_.BUSINESS_IDENTIFIER,
    this_.ENVIRONMENT,
    this_.HOST_NAME,
    global_transaction_id,
    business_identifier
order by
    y7_ desc limit ?
```

and then

```
select
    status
from
    activity_monitor_transaction
where
    GLOBAL_TRANSACTION_ID=?
order by
    date_time DESC,
    CASE status
        WHEN 'COMPLETED'THEN 'd'
        WHEN 'FAILED' THEN 'c'
        WHEN 'TERMINATED' THEN 'b'
        WHEN 'STARTED' THEN 'a'
        ELSE 'z'
    END DESC LIMIT 1
```

But this is causing me performance issues as I have to execute the second query once per row.

This is the table script for postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE activity_monitor_transaction
(
  id numeric(11,0) NOT NULL,
  date_time timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL,
  global_transaction_id character varying(40) NOT NULL,
  repost_flag character(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'::bpchar,
  environment character varying(20),
  transaction_mode character varying(20),
  status character varying(20),
  step character varying(80),
  event character varying(20),
  event_code character varying(20),
  event_subcode character varying(20),
  summary character varying(200),
  business_identifier character varying(80),
  alternate_business_identifier character varying(80),
  domain character varying(20),
  process character varying(80),
  service_name character varying(80),
  service_version character varying(20),
  detail text,
  app_name character varying(80),
  app_user character varying(20),
  host_name character varying(80),
  thread_name character varying(200),
  CONSTRAINT activity_monitor_transact_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
  USING INDEX TABLESPACE actmon_data
)
```

and some data:

```
insert into ACTIVITY_MONITOR_TRANSACTION values 
(54938456,'2015-04-20 09:39:27','8d276718-eca7-4fd0-a266-d465181f911a','N','Perf','','STARTED','servicereq.p2p.rso.blaze.dedup.in.channel','PROCESS','','','','3100729','51174628','ERP','servicereq-p2p-rso-blaze','servicereq-p2p-rso-blaze','1.0.0-SNAPSHOT','','servicereq-p2p-rso-blaze','CIC','intintprf20','SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-88177');

insert into ACTIVITY_MONITOR_TRANSACTION values 
(54938505,'2015-04-20 09:45:27','8d276718-eca7-4fd0-a266-d465181f911a','N','Perf','','COMPLETED','servicereq.p2p.rso.blaze.service.out.channel','PROCESS','','','','3100729','51174628','ERP','servicereq-p2p-rso-blaze','servicereq-p2p-rso-blaze','1.0.0-SNAPSHOT','','servicereq-p2p-rso-blaze','CIC','intintprf20','SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-88177');

insert into ACTIVITY_MONITOR_TRANSACTION values 
(54938507,'2015-04-20 09:45:27','8d276718-eca7-4fd0-a266-d465181f911a','N','Perf','','FAILED','inputChannel','PROCESS','','','','3100729','','ERP','servicereq-p2p-rso-blaze','servicereq-p2p-rso-blaze','1.0.0-SNAPSHOT','','servicereq-p2p-rso-blaze','CIC','intintprf20','SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-88177');
```

Is there any way to mimic the **keep dense_rank** block into postgres in order to have just one query?

Comment: I believe folks who would want to help you, might need your table definition and the data, i.e. the table creation scripts and the insert statements. I have upvoted your question only because you have pointed out the portion where you need help. Now, please post the required details as I have suggested.

Comment: Added, hope that helps!

Comment: No. Sorry, but, that won't help. Just think, If I would give you the same, how would you create a table out of it? You need to reverse engineer, write your own create and insert statements. Why not provide the create and insert statements. I have tried my best to help you about how to ask a question, I hope you get your desired solution.

Comment: Have you tried to use something like `first_value(status) OVER (partition by global_transaction_id order by date_time, CASE ... END)` ?

Comment: Thanks Igor. It does not work because I would need to group by date_time. I would like to have the rows grouped by the other columns, so that rows with different date_times will be grouped, and the "count" will show the number of rows grouped. See the example above (I have edited)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PostgreSQL `WINDOW FUNCTIONS`

```
-- we only added infos to the activity_monitor_transaction
-- we are free to group by date_time or status
SELECT
  first_value(status) OVER w AS global_transaction_status,
  count(*) OVER w AS global_transaction_count,
  activity_monitor_transaction.*
FROM
  activity_monitor_transaction
WINDOW w AS (
  PARTITION BY global_transaction_id
  ORDER BY date_time DESC, id DESC
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
)
```

Comment: although in this case you will also need to have some way to de -dup because the window is not the same as `group by` - it will return one row per record in the activity table rather than a single row

Answer (score 1):

Sample code

```
CREATE TABLE prices
( 
 ticker VARCHAR2(3),
 pdate DATE,
 price FLOAT
);
INSERT INTO prices( ticker, pdate, price) VALUES ('usd', DATE'2016-10-22', 55.11);
INSERT INTO prices( ticker, pdate, price) VALUES ('usd', DATE'2016-10-22', 56.11);
INSERT INTO prices( ticker, pdate, price) VALUES ('usd', DATE'2016-10-25', 57.11);
INSERT INTO prices( ticker, pdate, price) VALUES ('usd', DATE'2016-10-25', 57.22);
INSERT INTO prices( ticker, pdate, price) VALUES ('usd', DATE'2016-10-27', 58.11);
INSERT INTO prices( ticker, pdate, price) VALUES ('usd', DATE'2016-11-29', 57.13);
INSERT INTO prices( ticker, pdate, price) VALUES ('usd', DATE'2016-11-29', 57.20);
INSERT INTO prices( ticker, pdate, price) VALUES ('eur', DATE'2016-11-22', 65.11);
INSERT INTO prices( ticker, pdate, price) VALUES ('eur', DATE'2016-11-22', 65.12);
INSERT INTO prices( ticker, pdate, price) VALUES ('eur', DATE'2016-11-25', 67.11);
INSERT INTO prices( ticker, pdate, price) VALUES ('eur', DATE'2016-11-27', 68.11);
INSERT INTO prices( ticker, pdate, price) VALUES ('chf', DATE'2016-11-22', 88.11);
INSERT INTO prices( ticker, pdate, price) VALUES ('chf', DATE'2016-11-25', 88.33);
INSERT INTO prices( ticker, pdate, price) VALUES ('chf', DATE'2016-11-25', 89.33);
```

Oracle code

```
SELECT 
  ticker,
  min(price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY pdate) as minfirstprice,
  max(price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY pdate) as maxfirstprice,
  min(price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY pdate) as minlastprice,
  max(price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY pdate) as maxlastprice,
  sum(price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY pdate) as sumfirstprice,
  sum(price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY pdate) as sumlastprice
FROM prices
GROUP BY ticker
ORDER BY ticker;
```

Postgresql code

```
with _prepare as (
    select ticker, pdate,
           min(price) over w as minprice,
           max(price) over w as maxprice,
           sum(price) over w as sumprice
    FROM prices
    WINDOW w AS (partition by ticker,pdate)    
)
SELECT distinct * from 
(
    select ticker,
           first_value(minprice) over w1 as minfirstprice,
           first_value(maxprice) over w1 as maxfirstprice,
           first_value(minprice) over w2 as minlastprice,
           first_value(maxprice) over w2 as maxlastprice,
           first_value(sumprice) over w1 as sumfirstprice,
           first_value(sumprice) over w2 as sumlastprice
    from _prepare
    WINDOW w1 AS (partition by ticker ORDER BY pdate), 
           w2 AS (partition by ticker ORDER BY pdate desc)
) t2
ORDER BY ticker;
```