# Oracle to Postgres SQL syntax conversion

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I'm working on Oracle to Postgres conversion, I'm stuck with a single piece of code which is driving me nuts. I'm not sure how to use `SUM(VALUE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY START_DATE DESC) AS LATEST_VALUE` in Postgres.

I've referred [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750563/convert-keep-dense-rank-from-oracle-query-into-postgres) and that doesn't work work me. Since in my case the query has `GROUP BY` condition seems like pretty difficult in this case.

Here is the piece of code which is written for Oracle, and got stuck with converting to Postgres.

```
SELECT
    R_ID,
    S_TYPE,
    I_ID,
    M_TYPE,
    TRUNC(CAST( START_DATE, 'D') AS START_DATE,
    SUM(VALUE) AS SUM_VALUE,
    SUM(VALUE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY START_DATE DESC) AS LATEST_VALUE
FROM
    TABLEX
WHERE
    ACTIVE = 'Y'
GROUP BY
    R_ID,
    S_TYPE,
    I_ID,
    M_TYPE,
    TRUNC( START_DATE, 'D')
```

The most important thing is to get the DENSE_RANK is used for START_DATE and GROUP BY is done with TRUNC(START_DATE, 'D').

If anyone have any insight on this, Please let me know about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I removed the superfluous [tag:mysql] tag. Stack Overflow has a problem that they suggest mysql for any question related to SQL.

Comment: can you some sample data and expected output please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
    R_ID,
    S_TYPE,
    I_ID,
    M_TYPE,
    TRUNC(CAST( START_DATE, 'D') AS START_DATE,
    SUM(VALUE) AS SUM_VALUE,
    SUM(CASE START_DATE WHEN my_date THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS LATEST_VALUE
FROM (
    SELECT *,
          max( START_DATE ) OVER (partition by  R_ID,
                                                S_TYPE,
                                                I_ID,
                                                M_TYPE,
                                                TRUNC( START_DATE, 'D')
          ) As my_date
    FROM TABLEX
    WHERE
        ACTIVE = 'Y'
) x
GROUP BY
    R_ID,
    S_TYPE,
    I_ID,
    M_TYPE,
    TRUNC( START_DATE, 'D')
```

Neither PostgreSQL nor any other RDBMS I know support Oracle's KEEP DENSE RANK syntax, you must simulate this function somehow, the above is such a simulation.